# Onclick function not triggering when button is clicked

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to iterate over a specific column in a csv file using pandas. Here is my code:

```
data = pd.read_csv("2-22-19 to 2-25-19.csv", usecols=['tags'])


for x in data.iterrows():
    print(x)
```

How do I get x to just be the content of the cell? It is printing out values like:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TDg72.png)

Comment: What does your csv file look like? Which column do you want to print? The "cell" has to be from a specific column from each row. Also, your question title is kind of misleading. Nevertheless, if you want to access a specific column you can do: `for _, x in data.iterrows(): print(x['col_name'])`

Comment: thanks that helped me

Comment: You can iterate over the column values directly: `for x in data['col_name']: print(x)`. And could you please change the title of the question to match the actual question? :)